# Bash infinite loop sleep having strange behavior (NGINX/PHP-FPM/PGSQL)

Tags: multithreading, bash, curl, nginx

I'm not sure it should be in stackoverflow or serverfault. I post here because it may be a programming problem.

I have this infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

MESSAGE="XXX0"
RESULT=`curl "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`

while :
do


    if [[ "$RESULT" == "DONE" ]] 
    then
        RESULT=`curl "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`
    elif [[ "$RESULT" == "NONE" ]] 
    then
        sleep 5
        RESULT=`curl "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`
    else
        printf "%s %s\n" "$(date --rfc-3339='seconds'): ELSE1-" "$RESULT"   >> /var/log/XXX/loopXXX-`date --rfc-3339='date'`
        sleep 5
        RESULT=`curl "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`

        if [[ "$RESULT" == "DONE" ]] 
        then
            RESULT=`curl "http://jsomepage.php?thread=0"`
        elif [[ "$RESULT" == "NONE" ]] 
        then
            sleep 5
            RESULT=`curl "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`
        else
            printf "STOP"
            break
        fi
    fi

done
```

I have 3 loops doing the same job and requesting thread 0 to 2. In the DBtable the PHP page request, there is a column thread. So the three loops query the same table (read/write) but never the same lines.

The problem I experience is that in some nights (almost no activity), one loop doesn't request a page for several hours (I checked in NGINX access log). This only happen sometimes and the server is way more powerfull than needed yet.

Is there problems using infinite loop with curl? In total I have around 10 loops (different pages/tables) but they have a 10s sleep instead of 5s.

Is there a problem in my script with memory/curl? Have you ever experienced something similar?

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the `curl` lines is probably taking much longer than you expect to execute.

You should use [`curl`'s `--max-time` parameter](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-m) in order to limit the duration of any single execution to something sane.  It expects seconds.

e.g.

```
RESULT=`curl --max-time 10 "http://somepage.php?thread=0"`
```

Note that you may now encounter failures where instead you had been seeing long delays.  Checking the output might be satisfactory for your application, but return codes are the path to enlightenment.  You may even want to use the "`-e`" option in your shebang and/or create a handler to be used with a `trap` for `ERR`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set max timeouts for your every curl command to prevent them from hanging. Example:

```
curl -m 50 ...
```